# Delete the content between HTML tags including the tags themselves in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

There are about 100 files and I need to go through each of them and delete all the data which is between `<style>` and `</style>` + delete these tags too.

For example

```html
<html>
<head> <title> Example </title> </head>
<style>
p{color: red;
background-color: #FFFF;
}
div {......
...
}
</style>
<body>
<p> hi I'm a paragraph. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

should become

```html
<html>
<head> <title> Example </title> </head>
<body>
<p> hi I'm a paragraph. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, in some files the style pattern is like

```html
<style type="text/css"> blah </style>
```

or

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$url_path/gridsorting.css">
```

I need to remove all 3 patterns. How do I do this in Perl?

Comment: It looks like you're seeking to process HTML with regular expressions. That's an [astonishingly bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $qfn = 'a.html';

my $doc  = XML::LibXML->load_html( location => $qfn );
my $root = $doc->documentElement();

for my $style_node ($root->findnodes('//style')) {
   $style_node->parentNode()->removeChild($style_node);
}

{
   open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
      or die;
   print($fh $doc->toStringHTML());
}
```

It correctly handles:

- style elements with attributes or spaces in the tag,
- style elements that span more than one line,
- style tags that span more than one line,
- lines that contain part of a style element and something else,
- documents with multiple style elements,
- something that looks like a style tags in attribute values,
- something that looks like a style tags in CDATA blocks, and
- something that looks like a style tags in comments.

As of this update, the other solutions only handle 2 or 3 of these.

Comment: The output is this: http://pastebin.com/uWAamD19. It added DOCTYPE and <head></head> which I don't need.

Comment: How can I remove the DOCTYPE and <head></head>? I don't know why it's generating automatically.

Comment: You can't. That's what it does. There's no reason to remove them.

Comment: @fxzuz, Your change is not equivalent. I do not want to import anything! Omitting parens around arguments leads to numerous problems, and makes it harder to see where the argument lists ends. Reverting your changes.

Comment: @fxzuz, Why did you only remove those parens? There were numerous others you could have removed. You weren't even consistent with yourself!

Comment: @Chankey Pathak, The DOCTYPE will always be the first line, so that's easy to remove.

Answer (score 4):

Ikegami is right, you really should use at least an HTML/XML parser to do this task. Personally I like using the [`Mojo::DOM`](http://p3rl.org/Mojo%3a%3aDOM) parser. This is a Document-Object Model interface to your HTML and it supports [CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), making it really flexible when you need it. This is a pretty easy one for it however:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $content = <<'END';
<html>
<head> <title> Example </title> </head>
<style>
p{color: red;
background-color: #FFFF;
}
div {......
...
}
</style>
<body>
<p> hi I'm a paragraph. </p>
</body>
</html>
END

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $content );
$dom->find('style')->pluck('remove');

print $dom;
```

The `pluck` method is a little confusing, but its really just a shorthand for the doing a method on each resultant object. The analogous line could be

```
$dom->find('style')->each(sub{ $_->remove });
```

which is a little more understandable but less cute.

---

After reading your edit that you have to deal with more that just your basic form, I have to stress even further that this is why you use a parser for modifying HTML rather than let your regex grow to ridiculous proportions.

Now lets say that the `$content` variable also contained these lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$url_path/gridsorting.css">
<link rel="icon" href="somefile.jpg">
```

where you want to remove the first one, and not the second. You can do this in one of two ways.

```
$dom->find('link')->each( sub{ $_->remove if $_->{rel} eq 'stylesheet' } );
```

This mechanism uses the object methods (and Mojo::DOM exposes attributes as hash keys) to remove only the `link` tags which have `rel=stylesheet`. You can however use CSS3 selectors to only `find` those elements, however, and since Mojo::DOM has full CSS3 selector support you can do

```
$dom->find('link[rel=stylesheet]')->pluck('remove');
```

CSS3 selector statements can be joined with a comma to find all tags matching either selector, so we can simply include the line

```
$dom->find('style, link[rel=stylesheet]')->pluck('remove');
```

and get rid of all your offensive stylesheets in one fell swoop!

Comment: Can you tell that I'm proctoring an exam and have nothing better to do but consider CSS3 selectors. :-)

Comment: Sadly I have to use Perl 5.8 :/

Comment: My company won't let me use any version of perl > 5.8.5

Comment: While I can imagine that a company has strong policy for using a specific version of Perl for live shared programs (think webapps or db interaction), what you are doing is a one-off admin task. If they are preventing you from using the right tool for the job, they are preventing you from doing your job.

Comment: I did it somehow, but yes I had to write a shit code for that. I feel bad :| anyways, thanks for the answer, it will help me in future (perhaps). cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

One more possible solution is to use `HTML::TreeBuilder`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder 5; # Ensure weak references in use

foreach my $file_name (@ARGV) {
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new; # empty tree
  $tree->parse_file($file_name);
  # print "Hey, here's a dump of the parse tree of $file_name:\n";
  # $tree->dump; # a method we inherit from HTML::Element
  foreach my $e ($tree->look_down(_tag => "style")) {
      $e->delete();
  }
  foreach my $e ($tree->look_down(_tag => "link", rel => "stylesheet")) {
      $e->delete();
  }
  print "And here it is, bizarrely rerendered as HTML:\n",
    $tree->as_HTML, "\n";

  # Now that we're done with it, we must destroy it.
  $tree = $tree->delete; # Not required with weak references
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed '/<style>/,/<\/style>/d' file.txt
```

Results:

```
<html>
<head> <title> Example </title> </head>
<body>
<p> hi I'm a paragraph. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That assumes there's never anything but style elements on one line. That assumes `<style>...</style>` doesn't appears in attributes values, CDATA and comments. etc

Comment: @ikegami: You are correct. I made some assumptions about the input.  An XML parser should be used +1

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print unless(/<style>/.../<\/style>/)' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
<html>
<head> <title> Example </title> </head>
<style>
p{color: red;
background-color: #FFFF;
}
div {......
...
}
</style>
<body>
<p> hi I'm a paragraph. </p>
</body>
</html>


> perl -lne 'print unless(/<style>/.../<\/style>/)' temp
<html>
<head> <title> Example </title> </head>
<body>
<p> hi I'm a paragraph. </p>
</body>
</html>
>
```

if you want to do it inplace,then:

```
perl -i -lne 'print unless(/<style>/.../<\/style>/)' your_file
```

Comment: That assumes there's never anything but style elements on one line. That assumes the style elements have no attributes. That assumes `<style>...</style>` doesn't appears in attributes values, CDATA and comments. etc

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way， you can try the following:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $line = << 'END';
<html>
<head> <title> Example </title> </head>
<style>
p{color: red;
background-color: #FFFF;
}
div {......
...
}
</style>
<body>
<p> hi I'm a paragraph. </p>
</body>
</html>
END

$line =~ s{<style[^>]*.*?</style>.}{}gs;
print $line;
```